# openstack aodh charm remains in waiting state “'shared-db' incomplete”

Tags: mysql, openstack, cloud-computing, mysql-cluster, juju

please I need your help, We are running a platform built on the openstack framework(Rocky). Recently we decided to install the Aodh service on our platform so as to enable autoscaling with Heat. Our infrastructure is running mysql/percona-cluster in a cluster, , after adding relation between aodh and MySQL, the aodh charm goes into waiting state instead of active state. We tried deploying aodh in a demo environment that is running a single node of mysql and the deployment successfully goes into active state after all the relevant relations are added. We are thinking that this might be an issue with ha-cluster, but we haven't seen anything in the logs that points to the source of this issue.

**Openstack Version: Openstack Rocky**

**Ubuntu version: 18.04**

**JUJU STATUS**:

**Unit Workload Agent Machine Public address Ports Message**

aodh/4* waiting idle 93 10.10.2.2 8042/tcp 'shared-db' incomplete

**JUJU LOG**:

`tracer: ++ queue handler hooks/relations/mysql-shared/requires.py:16:joined 2020-12-26 21:57:41 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Invoking reactive handler: hooks/relations/mysql-shared/requires.py:16:joined 2020-12-26 21:57:42 DEBUG juju-log shared-db:157: tracer: set flag shared-db.connected 2020-12-26 21:57:42 DEBUG juju-log shared-db:157: tracer> tracer: main dispatch loop, 4 handlers queued tracer: ++ queue handler hooks/relations/tls-certificates/requires.py:109:broken:certificates tracer: ++ queue handler reactive/aodh_handlers.py:45:setup_amqp_req tracer: ++ queue handler reactive/aodh_handlers.py:55:setup_database tracer: ++ queue handler reactive/aodh_handlers.py:64:setup_endpoint 2020-12-26 21:57:42 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Invoking reactive handler: reactive/aodh_handlers.py:45:setup_amqp_req 2020-12-26 21:57:43 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Invoking reactive handler: reactive/aodh_handlers.py:55:setup_database 2020-12-26 21:57:44 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Invoking reactive handler: reactive/aodh_handlers.py:64:setup_endpoint 2020-12-26 21:57:46 WARNING juju-log shared-db:157: configure_ssl method is DEPRECATED, please use configure_tls instead. 2020-12-26 21:57:46 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Invoking reactive handler: hooks/relations/tls-certificates/requires.py:109:broken:certificates 2020-12-26 21:57:46 DEBUG juju-log shared-db:157: Running _assess_status() 2020-12-26 21:57:52 INFO juju-log shared-db:157: Reactive main running for hook shared-db-relation-changed 2020-12-26 21:57:52 DEBUG juju-log shared-db:157: tracer> tracer: starting handler dispatch, 41 flags set tracer: set flag amqp.available tracer: set flag amqp.connected tracer: set flag aodh-installed tracer: set flag charm.installed tracer: set flag charms.openstack.do-default-certificates.available tracer: set flag charms.openstack.do-default-cluster.available tracer: set flag charms.openstack.do-default-upgrade-charm tracer: set flag config.default.action-managed-upgrade tracer: set flag config.default.debug tracer: set flag config.default.dns-ha tracer: set flag config.default.haproxy-client-timeout tracer: set flag config.default.haproxy-connect-timeout tracer: set flag config.default.haproxy-queue-timeout tracer: set flag config.default.haproxy-server-timeout tracer: set flag config.default.os-admin-hostname tracer: set flag config.default.os-admin-network tracer: set flag config.default.os-internal-hostname tracer: set flag config.default.os-internal-network tracer: set flag config.default.os-public-hostname tracer: set flag config.default.os-public-network tracer: set flag config.default.region tracer: set flag config.default.ssl_ca tracer: set flag config.default.ssl_cert tracer: set flag config.default.ssl_key tracer: set flag config.default.use-policyd-override tracer: set flag config.default.use-syslog tracer: set flag config.default.vip tracer: set flag config.default.vip_cidr tracer: set flag config.default.vip_iface tracer: set flag config.default.worker-multiplier tracer: set flag config.set.openstack-origin tracer: set flag config.set.region tracer: set flag config.set.use-internal-endpoints tracer: set flag config.set.vip_cidr tracer: set flag config.set.vip_iface tracer: set flag haproxy.stat.password tracer: set flag identity-service.available tracer: set flag identity-service.available.auth tracer: set flag identity-service.connected tracer: set flag shared-db.connected tracer: set flag ssl.enabled 2020-12-26 21:57:53 DEBUG juju-log shared-db:157: tracer> tracer: hooks phase, 1 handlers queued tracer: ++ queue handler hooks/relations/mysql-shared/requires.py:20:changed`